# xpath regular expression for xml

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I would like to read an xml using xpath regular expression.

The tags can be `<PaymentCard>` or `<ns2:PaymentCard>`.

I need to find a common regular expression to read both of the tags.

Currently I am able to read only `<PaymentCard>` tag using below code:

```
paymentCardPath = xpath.compile("//PaymentCard");
```

Comment: There's no regular expression involved.

Comment: Is it really `ns2.PaymentCard` or actually `ns2:PaymentCard`?

Comment: In XPath 2.0 you can use `//*[matches(name(), 'PaymentCard')]` or `//*[ends-with(name(), 'PaymentCard')]`

Comment: its actually ns2:PaymentCard

Answer (score 2):

In a supplementary comment you clarified that the two names in question are actually `PaymentCard` and `ns2:PaymentCard` - that is, two names that have the same local part and different namespace URIs.

In XPath 2.0 you can find names using the local part alone using `//*:PaymentCard`. The XPath 1.0 equivalent is `//*[local-name()='PaymentCard']`.

Comment: Though strictly speaking that will also find `ns1:PaymentCard`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the union operator:

```
//*[self::PaymentCard | self::ns2.PaymentCard]
```

Note that's an XPath Expression (version 1.0), not a regular expression.